# Getting undefined when trying to access elements in an array Typescript

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, promise

When I try to access elements in an array I am getting undefined even though in the console it shows that the array has values. i.e. console.log(y) => ['a', 'b', 'c'] ... y[0] => undefined.

```
export const calculateFinalGrades = (clazz: Array<Clazz>) => {
  let gradeMap = new Map();
  let clz = clazz;
  clz.forEach((clzs) => {
    if(clzs && clzs.gradeWeights !== undefined) {
      clzs.gradeWeights.forEach((weight) => {
      })
    } else {
      console.error('NOT FOUND IN ARRAY')
    }
  })
  
  let fGrade = 0;
  let y = clazz;
  console.log(y);
  console.log(y[0]);
  
  if(y[0] !== undefined) {
    console.log('WHY IS y[0] UNDEFINED')
    for(let i = 0; i < y[0].students[i].grades.size; i++) {
      
      let grades = clazz[0].students[i].grades;
      grades.forEach((value, key) => {
        fGrade += gradeMap.get(key) * parseInt(value);
        console.log(value);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

[console snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYIgF.png)
Notice the line numbers.[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6BT7.png)

I am using multiple asynchronous requests but I have done a good job in making sure the data is passed down to the next API call only after it resolves. I have also tried 'cloning' the array and then accessing the elements of the clone but I still get undefined

Comment: "*I am using multiple asynchronous requests*" - where? Nothing in the code you posted appears to be asynchronous.

Comment: What's up with the empty loop over `clzs.gradeWeights`?

Comment: "*I am getting undefined even though in the console it shows that the array has values*" - no. It shows that the array is empty, it prints `[]`. Only later the array is getting filled, this is what you see when you expand the object interactively.

Comment: The values of an array are lazy loaded in the console, ie. they aren't loaded until you click the button to expand the array.

Comment: Btw, no point in doing `let clz = clazz;` and `let y = clazz;`. Just always refer to `clazz` directly. Introducing many aliases for one and the same thing just make the code more confusing. Or did you expect those lines to [create copies of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085/1048572)? They don't.

Comment: "*I have done a good job in making sure the data is passed down to the next API call only after it resolves*" - if you need further help with this, please show the code that is doing the API call and calling `calculateFinalGrades`. "*I have also tried 'cloning' the array*" - in that case you would have clearly seen that the array still was empty when you cloned it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am going to close the ticket as my question is missing a lot of context.